# Problem about cross entropy

Tags: entropy

I would like to know why rewriting

$$- x * z + \log(1 + \exp(x))$$

as

$$\max(x, 0) - x * z + \log(1 + \exp(-|x|))$$

can ensure stability and avoid overflow?
Also, what is meant by stability?
Finally, why does the rewriting avoid overflow?

Answer (score 0):

About the overflow: $x > 0$ big means obviously overflow in $\exp(x)$. But in this case $\exp(x)$ is big, $1 + \exp(x)\approx\exp(x)$ and
$$\log(1 + \exp(x))\approx x$$

with the alternative formula,
$$
\max(x,0) + \log(1 + \exp(-|x|)) = x + \log(1 + \exp(-|x|))\approx x + 0 = x
$$
and $-|x| < 0\implies\exp(-|x|)$ does not cause overflow.